# Why does Clojure allow (eval 3) although 3 is not quoted?

Tags: clojure, lisp, eval

I'm learning Clojure and trying to understand reader, quoting, eval and homoiconicity by drawing parallels to Python's similar features.

In Python, one way to avoid (or postpone) evaluation is to wrap the expression between quotes, eg. `'3 + 4'`. You can evaluate this later using `eval`, eg. `eval('3 + 4')` yielding `7`. (If you need to quote only Python values, you can use `repr` function instead of adding quotes manually.)

In Lisp you use `quote` or `'` for quoting and `eval` for evaluating, eg. `(eval '(+ 3 4))` yielding `7`.

So in Python the "quoted" stuff is represented by a string, whereas in Lisp it's represented by a list which has `quote`as first item.

My question, finally: why does Clojure allow `(eval 3)` although `3` is not quoted? Is it just the matter of Lisp style (trying to give an answer instead of error wherever possible) or are there some other reasons behind it? Is this behavior essential to Lisp or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other answers have explained the mechanics, but I think the philosophical point is in the different ways lisp and python look at "code". In python, the only way to represent code is as a string, so of course attempting to evaluate a non-string will fail. Lisp has richer data structures for code: lists, numbers, symbols, and so forth. So the expression `(+ 1 2)` is a list, containing a symbol and two numbers. When evaluating a list, you must first evaluate each of its elements.

So, it's perfectly natural to need to evaluate a number in the ordinary course of running lisp code. To that end, numbers are defined to "evaluate to themselves", meaning they are the same after evaluation as they were before: just a number. The `eval` function applies the same rules to the bare "code snippet" `3` that the compiler would apply when compiling, say, the third element of a larger expression like `(+ 5 3)`. For numbers, that means leaving it alone.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer would be that numbers (and symbols, and strings, for example) evaluate to themselves. Quoting instruct lisp (the reader) to pass unevaluated whatever follows the quote. `eval` then gets that list as you wrote it, but without the quote, and then evaluates it (in the case of `(eval '(+ 3 4))`, `eval` will evaluate a function call (`+`) over two arguments).

What happens with that last expression is the following:

1. When you hit enter, the expression is evaluated. It contain a normal function call (`eval`) and some arguments.
2. The arguments are evaluated. The first argument contains a quote, which tells the reader to *produce* what is after the quote (the actual `(+ 3 4)` list).
3. There are no more arguments, and the actual function call is evaluated. This means calling the `eval` function with the *list* `(+ 3 4)` as argument.
4. The `eval` function does the same steps again, finding the normal function `+` and the arguments, and applies it, obtaining the result.

Comment: I thought that in `(eval '(+ 3 4))` eval only removes the quote and returns what's after the quote, and `(+ 3 4)` gets evaluated somewhere else (by another `eval`?).

Comment: No, that's not the case. I'll expanded my answer to clarify in more detail the steps.

Comment: you are confusing evaluating a lisp form with using a REPL. QUOTE in Lisp also is not an instruction for the reader, but a built-in special operator.

Comment: Mmm... I introduced that "enter" to exemplify the moment, in a REPL, when evaluation starts. I'm not confusing it because hitting *enter* in the REPL causes evaluation. Also, QUOTE is a special operator, but the quote itself (`'`) is usually interpreted by the reader (whatever it is converted into is not that important in this case, right? The fact is that it causes the argument not to be evaluated.)

Comment: The quote character followed by a form is converted into a quote form by the reader. 'foo is (quote foo). The reader does not 'interpret' quote. It just converts a quote character - you can write the quote form directly. A quote form instructs the evaluator (not the reader!) to return the quoted value as is.

Answer (score 3):

What should `3` evaluate to? It makes the most sense that Lisp evaluates a number to itself. Would we want to require numbers to be quoted in code? That would not be very convenient and extremely problematic:

Instead of

```
(defun add-fourtytwo (n)
   (+ n 42))
```

we would have to write

```
(defun add-fourtytwo (n)
   (+ n '42))
```

Every number in code would need to be quoted. A missing quote would trigger an error. That's not something one would want to use.

As a side note, imagine what happens when you want to use `eval` in your code.

```
(defun example ()
  (eval 3))
```

Above would be wrong. Numbers would need to be quoted.

```
 (defun example ()
   (eval '3))
```

Above would be okay, but generating an error at runtime. Lisp evaluates `'3` to the number 3. But then calling `eval` on the number would be an error, since they need to be quoted.

So we would need to write:

```
(defun example ()
   (eval ''3))
```

That's not very useful...

Numbers have be always self-evaluating in Lisp history. But in earlier Lisp implementations some other data objects, like arrays, were not self-evaluating. Again, since this is a huge source of errors, Lisp dialects like Common Lisp have defined that all data types (other than lists and symbols) are self-evaluating.

Comment: I guess I have trouble seeing why does reader read source text `3` in as integer 3. In many languages source text `3` would be read in as `IntLiteral(3)`, ie. different datatypes are used in phases before evaluation. Somehow this differentiation makes things clearer for me. Can you explain what is the benefit of using same datatypes both for representing code and for representing live values?

Comment: @Alvar: it's not a question of benefits. In Lisp source code is data, not text. EVAL is defined to take source code as a data expression, not a string representation. The reader does not read Lisp source text. The reader reads s-expressions and returns data. The reader does not know anything about the Lisp programming language. Its only purpose is to convert a textual s-expression to data. This simplifies the reader, since it does not need to understand the syntax of the Lisp programming language - it just implements the syntax of a data representation, of s-expressions.

Comment: Now, this moved something in my brain, thanks :) I still need to digest it a bit ...

Comment: @Aivar One benefit of sharing a representation for code and data is that you can "rewrite" an s-expression that represents code just like you can manipulate s-expressions that represent data. This allows you to build functions programmatically, makes macro-systems (more) straightforward, etc.

Comment: @Matt, at runtime I could also build and tweak data structures like `Expr(BinOp('+', Var('x'), IntLiteral(3)))`, as they are found in AST-s, but agreed, it would be easier with simpler data structures.

Answer (score 2):

To answer this question we need to look at `eval` definition in lisp. E.g. in [CLHS](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_eval.html) there is definition:

> Syntax: eval form => result*
>
> Arguments and Values: 
>   form - a form.
>   results - the values yielded by the evaluation of form.

Where `form` is

> 1. any object meant to be evaluated.
> 2. a symbol, a compound form, or a self-evaluating object.
> 3. (for an operator, as in `<<operator>> form'') a compound form having that operator as its first element.`A quote form is a
>      constant form.''

In your case number "3" is `self-evaluating object`. `Self-evaluating object` is `a form that is neither a symbol nor a cons is defined to be a self-evaluating object`. I believe that for clojure we can just replace `cons` by `list` in this definition.

In clojure only `lists` are interpreted by `eval` as function calls. Other data structures and objects are evaluated as self-evaluating objects.

`'(+ 3 4)` is equal to `(list '+ 3 4)`. `'` (transformed by reader to `quote` function) just avoid evaluation of given form. So in expression `(eval '(+ 3 4))` `eval` takes list data structure `('+ 3 4)` as argument.